# Random.nextInt(int) is [slightly] biased

Tags: java, random

Namely, it will never generate more than 16 even numbers in a row with some specific `upperBound` parameters:

```
Random random = new Random();

int c = 0;
int max = 17;
int upperBound = 18;

while (c <= max) {
    int nextInt = random.nextInt(upperBound);
    boolean even = nextInt % 2 == 0;
    if (even) {
        c++;
    } else {
        c = 0;
    }
}
```

In this example the code will loop forever, while when `upperBound` is, for example, 16, it terminates quickly.

What can be the reason of this behavior? There are some notes in the method's javadoc, but I failed to understand them.

---

**UPD1**: The code seems to terminate with odd upper bounds, but may stuck with even ones

---

**UPD2**:
I modified the code to capture the statistics of `c` as suggested in the comments:

```
Random random = new Random();

int c = 0;
long trials = 1 << 58;
int max = 20;
int[] stat = new int[max + 1];

while (trials > 0) {
    while (c <= max && trials > 0) {
        int nextInt = random.nextInt(18);
        boolean even = nextInt % 2 == 0;
        if (even) {
            c++;
        } else {
            stat[c] = stat[c] + 1;
            c = 0;
        }
        trials--;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stat));
```

Now it tries to reach `20` evens in the row - to get better statistics, and the `upperBound` is still `18`.

The results turned out to be more than surprising:

```
[16776448, 8386560, 4195328, 2104576, 1044736, 
 518144, 264704, 132096, 68864, 29952, 15104, 
 12032, 1792, 3072, 256, 512, 0, 256, 0, 0]
```

At first it decreases as expected by the factor of 2, but note the last line! Here it goes crazy and the captured statistics seem to be completely weird.

Here is a bar plot in log scale:

[image: c statistics]

How `c` gets the value `17` 256 times is yet another mystery

Comment: Could you print out `c` before you set it to `0`, see if there's any sort of pattern in the number of evens you can get in a row? Also, how does this show it's biased? Is the behavior different for odd numbers? All this shows is that it's not truly random. But we knew that already.

Comment: Not an answer, but if you use a `SecureRandom` instead, the code terminates as expected.

Comment: LCGs are notoriously bad, especially in their low-order bits. For any serious use of random numbers, like simulations or Monte Carlo methods, LCGs are totally unacceptable. Use a good external PRNG library.

Comment: Why exactly *should* it deliver > 16 even numbers in a row with range of 18? Surely you can't reasonably expect more than 9 out of 18?

Comment: @EJP If it were really random, 17 consecutive even numbers *should* happen on average every 2^17 numbers or 130k. That is what is observed when using a better generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html:

> An instance of this class is used to generate a stream of
>   pseudorandom numbers. The class uses a 48-bit seed, which is modified
>   using a linear congruential formula. (See Donald Knuth, The Art of
>   Computer Programming, Volume 3, Section 3.2.1.)
>
> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the
>   same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and
>   return identical sequences of numbers. [...]

It is a *pseudo*-random number generator. This means that you are not actually rolling a dice but rather use a formula to calculate the next "random" value based on the current random value. To creat the illusion of randomisation a `seed` is used. The seed is the first value used with the formula to generate the random value.

Apparently javas random implementation (the "formula"), does not generate more than 16 even numbers in a row.

This behaviour is the reason why the `seed` is usually initialized with the time. Deepending on when you start your program you will get different results.

The benefits of this approach are that you can generate repeatable results. If you have a game generating "random" maps, you can remember the seed to regenerate the same map if you want to play it again, for instance.

For true random numbers some operating systems provide special devices that generate "randomness" from external events like mousemovements or network traffic. However i do not know how to tap into those with java.

From the Java doc for **secureRandom**:

> Many SecureRandom implementations are in the form of a pseudo-random
>   number generator (PRNG), which means they use a deterministic
>   algorithm to produce a pseudo-random sequence from a true random seed.
>   Other implementations may produce true random numbers, and yet others
>   may use a combination of both techniques.

Note that secureRandom does **NOT** guarantee *true* random numbers either.

### Why changing the seed does not help

Lets assume random numbers would only have the range 0-7.
Now we use the following formula to generate the next "random" number:

```
 next = (current + 3) % 8
```

the sequence becomes `0 3 6 1 4 7 2 5`.

If you now take the seed `3` all you do is to change the starting point.

In this simple implementation that only uses the previous value, every value may occur only once before the sequence wraps arround and starts again. Otherwise there would be an unreachable part.

E.g. imagine the sequence `0 3 6 1 3 4 7 2 5`. The numbers `0,4,7,2 and 5` would never be generated more than once(deepending on the seed they might be generated never), since once the sequence loops 3,6,1,3,6,1,... .

Simplified pseudo random number generators can be thought of a permutation of all numbers in the range and you use the seed as a starting point. If they are more advanced you would have to replace the permutation with a list in which the same numbers might occur multiple times.

More complex generators can have an internal state, allowing the same number to occur several times in the sequence, since the state lets the generator know where to continue.

Comment: Yes, apparently there is a bias in the implementation - so I would like to understand why it's where. For instance, if I used `Math.abs(random.nextInt()) % upperBound` or, God forbid, `(int) (random.nextDouble() * upperBound)` it terminates as expected

Comment: Again, no matter what `seed` I use (tried a bunch of them), it never terminates with `upperBound=18`

Comment: @AlexeyGrigorev: I don't know if you read the last section before you commented. If you are asking why it was implemented this way: There is no way to generate true randomness without using external events. That is why http://www.random.org/ exists for example

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of Random uses a simple linear congruential formula.  Such formulae have a natural periodicity and all sorts of non-random patterns in the sequence they generate.

What you are seeing is an artefact of one of these patterns ... nothing deliberate.  It is not an example of bias.  Rather it is an example of [auto-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation).

If you need better (more "random") numbers, then you need to use `SecureRandom` rather than `Random`.

And the answer to *"why was it implemented that way is"* ... performance.  A call to `Random.nextInt` can be completed in tens or hundreds of clock cycles.  A call to `SecureRandom` is likely to be at least 2 orders of magnitude slower, possibly more.

Answer (score 1):

For portability, Java specifies that implementations *must* use the inferior LCG method for java.util.Random.  This method is completely unacceptable for any serious use of random numbers like complex simulations or Monte Carlo methods.  Use an add-on library with a better PRNG algorithm, like Marsaglia's MWC or KISS. Mersenne Twister and Lagged Fibonacci Generators are often OK as well.

I'm sure there are Java libraries for these algorithms. I have a C library with Java bindings if that will work for you: [ojrandlib](http://github.com/lcrocker/ojrandlib).